# DSE: Solr indexing delay interferes with integrations tests

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-node-driver

I'm using Datastax enterprise with several Cassandra, and Solr indexes, using the node.js driver. I have noticed an unfortunate thing when writing integration tests that run tests over solr.

In these tests there is a setup phase that writes records to Cassandra. The following step queries Solr and assets some data.

The thing is that since it might take Solr some time to index data from Cassandra, I see no way to make the assertion step to wait for Solr indexing to complete.

I've tried modifying solrconfig autoSoftCommit/maxTime to 1, and turn real time indexing (true), but it only works partially.

Is there a way to make the node.js drive insert methods to wait for solr indexing completion? Is there a way to solve this issue without delaying assertion with some random timeout?